# VSTS build with multiple repos

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

My team uses VSTS for CI/CD of a web project. In order to keep our code separated, we use two separate repositories for front-end and back-end.

Two questions are raised by this:

1. How do I set up a build that merges the build artifacts from the two repositories into a single release?
2. How do I trigger this single build/release process from each repository separately?

Comment: You can have multiple build artifacts linked to a single release definition, but as far as I know, only one build can trigger that release.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First step is to create a CI build for both repositories. Once you have them compiling and generating the necessary artifacts, you need to create a single CD release. At the top of the editor, there is an `Artifacts` tab.

[image: Artifacts Tab]

Once there, you can link multiple builds or release to it. Simply click the `Link an artifact source` and add your two CI builds.

[image: Artifacts Tab Contents]

Next, move to the `Triggers` tab. Here you can add triggers for a successful  completion from any or all of the CI builds.

[image]

When you add a task to your release and need to access an artifact, it will give you an option to use a `Linked Artifact` or a `URL Artifact`. Select the `Linked Artifact` and then click the three dot browse button for the artifact path. You will get a screen like the one below allowing you to locate the linked artifact between your two builds.

[image]

Comment: After I have done this, I get `More than one package matched with specified pattern: D:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip. Please restrain the search pattern.` because there are 2 zip files that came from the 2 sources.
How do I get them to continue deployment.

Comment: @RoyB You will need to fully qualify the zip file and break it up into either multiple steps or multiple phases.