# Angular application from Azure Pipeline into App Service Directory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

We have an Angular 7 application on one git repository and an ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web API on another git repository.  We use Azure pipelines to deploy both repos into an Azure App Service.

I have successfully been able to configure the Web API to deploy to the root directory and the Angular client into a wwwrooot sub directory.

However, in order to achieve this I need to configure the wwwroot sub-directory as an application, which makes the application fail with HTTP 404.  Once I change the settings to be "Directory" in the Azure app service, everything works as normal.

Is there a way to have the Angular pipeline deploy to the sub-directory while configured as Directory instead of Application?

[image]

Thank you,

Comment: I dont think so. And I also don't think this is a good idea. The API and the Angular app are both their own app and should each have a dedicated app service. This way, you can scale each separately as needed.

Comment: Thank you. VS deploys both this way. So its not unusual.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue from within the pipelines.  Following this post ([VSTS build with multiple repos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141337/vsts-build-with-multiple-repos)) I added the FE artifacts to the pipeline and simply copy it's dist contents to the wwwroot folder of the API build folder.  Then I simply deploy everything to App Services and now both the API and Angular App are deployed on the same server and working.

Hope this helps someone.